# Converting String to Date is always 2 hours behind

Tags: ios, swift

I know this is a topic with several answers and whilst maybe i missed something similar to mine, in all my effort i've looked but can't find the same thing:

I have a string of date format:

> 24/12/2019 10:34 AM

I am trying to convert it to Date type, but this is what i get when i print the converted date:

> 2019-12-24 08:34:00 +0000

It is ALWAYS 2 hours behind.

I have tried:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CAT")
```

and

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
```

to absolutely no avail. Also, the printed date is not formatted according to my required format

> dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a

My code is as below:

```
var dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "CAT")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "24/12/2019 10:34 AM")
print(date)
```

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: No it's not. Date is always UTC/GMT.

Comment: If you want a date object to print in a specific format you need to convert it to a string first. Try `print(dateFormatter.string(from: date!))` for a quick test

Comment: When you're printing `Date` object it uses `Date.description` that will always use that format and zero offset timezone.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you are saying that the string format -> dateFormatter.string(from: date) would print the accurate date? Geez if the print method accepts printing the date object as is i thought it would also just print the correct one

Comment: @T.Mas and how exactly `print` supposed to guess the format you wanted it to use without you using `DateFormatter`?

Comment: No I am saying that it is the accurate (the one you want) _format_

Comment: The date is correct. `2019-12-24 08:34:00 +0000` and `2019-12-24 10:34:00 +0200` is the same point in time

Comment: @user28434 it wouldn't be guessing because variable date is equal to dateFormatter which already holds all the formats specified, so it made sense to me for a bit. i used DateFormatter

Comment: @T.Mas, `Date` and `DateFormatter` cannot be equal. `Date` contains information about point in time and nothing else, `DateFormatter` contains information about translating `Date` to `String` and back.

Comment: thanks @vadian, i was also confused because the printed result did not comply with the date format

Comment: @T.Mas That's another story. Read Joakim's comments for that.

Comment: @T.Mas It does *comply with the date format* but as already stated `print` displays dates always in UTC (+0000)

Comment: @vadian, noted, glad i asked.